# Regarding table column inside table in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is the report that I have created using `xsl` and `xml` and this report is created in Pdf, Please click on the below `url` to see the report layout

[image]

and the xsl is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets" extension-element-prefixes="set" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-width="21cm" page-height="29.7cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
           <fo:region-body margin-bottom="2cm" margin-top="4cm"/>
          <fo:region-after extent="2cm"/>
          <fo:region-before extent="4cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
              </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" initial-page-number="1">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-after">
            <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  >
               </fo:block>
          <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="end">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="9.5cm"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="9.5cm"/>
               <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell
                                        text-align="center">
                    <fo:block text-align="left">
                                            Run:
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(  DepartmentSalesReport/CurrentDate , 6, 2 )" />
                                        /
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(  DepartmentSalesReport/CurrentDate , 9, 2 )" />
                                        /
                                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(  DepartmentSalesReport/CurrentDate , 1, 4 )" />
                                        @
                                    <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/currentTime" />
                                        </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="right">
                    <!--fo:block space-before="8mm">
                      <xsl:text>Keep this report for 6 months</xsl:text>
                    </fo:block-->
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell >
                    <fo:block space-before="8mm">Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="terminator"/></fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>

          </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>

        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before">
          <fo:block text-align-last="center" space-after="1.5cm">
            <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="4cm"/>
              <fo:table-column column-width="10cm"/>
               <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
               <fo:table-column column-width="2cm"/>
              <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell  font-size="9pt">
                    <fo:block>Store Number:
                      <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/store_code"/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                             <fo:block  text-align-last="center" font-size="14pt" font-weight="bold" space-after="1mm">
                                <fo:inline text-decoration="underline">Department Sales Report</fo:inline>
                               </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="right"   font-size="9pt">
                     <fo:block > 
                        <xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/tradingday"/>   
                     </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell text-align="right" font-size="9pt">
                    <xsl:variable name="date"><xsl:value-of select="DepartmentSalesReport/tradingdate"/></xsl:variable>
                    <fo:block> 
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($date,5,2)"/>/<xsl:value-of select="substring($date,7,2)"/>/<xsl:value-of select="substring($date,1,4)"/>
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
          <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
              <fo:table-column column-width="19cm"/>
          <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                   <fo:table-cell text-align="center">
                                      <fo:block text-align-last="center" font-size="9pt" >
                                        Summary of Sales by department, only those
                                            departments with activity (Sales,
                                            refunds, voids) will appear on this
                                            report.Use this report to monitor sales in
                                            key departments and make merchandising
                                            decisions as needed.
                          </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
          <fo:block font-size="9pt" >
           <fo:table table-layout="fixed" >
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.8cm" 
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-body>
                            <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9"> <fo:block color="black"
                        space-before.optimum="-8pt">
                        <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  />

                    </fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-row font-weight="bold">
                                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="left"><xsl:text>-------------------------Department-------------------</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>Net Sales</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>Qty</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-rows-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>% of Sales</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>--------Void--------</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
                            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:text>-------Return-------</xsl:text></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>        
                                </fo:table-row>
                                <fo:table-row font-weight="bold">
                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:text>Description</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Qty</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Qty</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>Amount</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                </fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-row >
                            <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9" > <fo:block color="black"
                        space-before.optimum="-8pt">

                    </fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                            </fo:table-row>

                            </fo:table-body>
                            </fo:table>
          </fo:block>
          <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" 
                               text-align="left" font-size="9pt"  />



     </fo:static-content>


        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <xsl:variable name="storeSales" select="sum(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentDesc/netSales)"/>
        <br/>
          <!--          <fo:block font-size="9pt" space-after="3mm" break-before="page">-->
            <xsl:for-each select="DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentDesc">
                    <fo:block font-size="9pt" space-after="1mm">
                    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" >
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.8cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm"
                                text-align="center"/>
                            <fo:table-column
                                column-width="1.6cm" />
                    <fo:table-body>
                        <xsl:variable name="levelNo"><xsl:value-of select="levelNbr"/></xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:variable name="levelCheck"><xsl:value-of select="level"/></xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:if test="$levelCheck!=''">
                                    <xsl:if test="$levelNo='2'">
                                    <fo:table-row>  
                                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9">
                                    <fo:block>
                                           <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                                    </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:if>
                     <fo:table-row >
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="level"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>

                                        <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="$levelNo!='2'">
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="prgpName"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                            </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <fo:table-cell>
                                                <fo:block text-align="left">
                                                    ***DEPT TOTAL*** </fo:block>
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                            </xsl:choose>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(netSales,'0.00')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(prodCount,'0')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>


                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <xsl:variable name="salesPercentage"><xsl:value-of select="format-number((netSales div $storeSales)*100, '###,##0')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$salesPercentage='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$salesPercentage!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$salesPercentage"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(postVoidQuantity,'0')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(postVoidAmount,'0.00')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(returnQuantity,'0')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                        <fo:table-cell>
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="format-number(returnAmount,'0.00')"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                        </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                        <xsl:if test="$levelNo='2'">
                                    <fo:table-row>  
                                    <fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="9">
                                    <fo:block>
                                           <xsl:text>&#160;</xsl:text>
                                    </fo:block>
                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                    </fo:table-row>
                                </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:if>
                    </fo:table-body>

                  </fo:table>
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:for-each>

            <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" text-align="left"
                font-size="9pt" space-before="3mm" />
            <fo:block font-size="9pt" space-after="4mm">

                <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="1.5cm" />
                    <fo:table-column column-width="4.5cm" />
                    <fo:table-column column-width="3.3cm" />

                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold"></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block text-align="left" space-after="4mm"
                                    space-before="3mm" font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>DEPARTMENT TOTALS</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>

                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>

                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>SS SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right">
                                    <xsl:variable name="ssSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/ssSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$ssSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$ssSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$ssSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>CIGARETTE SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block text-align="right" font-weight="bold">
                                <xsl:variable name="cigeratteSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/cigeratteSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$cigeratteSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$cigeratteSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$cigeratteSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block space-after="1.5mm" font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>LIQUOR SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right"
                                    space-after="4mm">
                                    <xsl:variable name="liquorSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/liquorSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$liquorSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$liquorSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$liquorSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" space-after="8mm">
                                    <xsl:text>TOTAL FRONT END SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right"
                                    space-after="4mm">
                                    <xsl:variable name="totalSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/totalSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$totalSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$totalSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$totalSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>

                    </fo:table-body>

                </fo:table>

            </fo:block> 



              <fo:block space-before="5mm" text-align="center" font-size="9pt" font-weight="bold" id="terminator">
                 <xsl:text></xsl:text>
          </fo:block>

        </fo:flow>

      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the xml is ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report Name="DepartmentSalesReport" Title="Department Sales Report"
    Description="Department Sales Report" Version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <InitParam Name="tradingdate" Type="java.lang.String" />
      <InitParam Name="tradingday" Type="java.lang.String" />
      <ReportBand BandType="HeaderBand" Name="DepartmentSalesReportBand">
        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="OutletSQL">
        <DataField Name="store_code" Type="Data" FieldName="ORGU_CODE" />
        </ReportElement>
        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="InitParams">
        <DataField Name="tradingdate" Type="Data" FieldName="tradingdate" />
        </ReportElement>
        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="InitParams">
        <DataField Name="tradingday" Type="Data" FieldName="tradingday" />
        </ReportElement>
    </ReportBand>
    <ReportBand BandType="DetailBand" Name="Terminal">
        <ReportElement Type="Detail" Name="DepartmentDesc" DataSource="DataSql">
            <DataField Name="level" Type="Data" FieldName="LEVEL"/>
            <DataField Name="levelNbr" Type="Data" FieldName="LEVELNBR"/>
            <DataField Name="prgpName" Type="Data" FieldName="PRGP_NAME"/>
            <DataField Name="prodCount" Type="Data" FieldName="PROD_COUNT"/>
            <DataField Name="netSales" Type="Data" FieldName="NET_SALES"/>
            <DataField Name="postVoidQuantity" Type="Data" FieldName="POST_VOID_QUANTITY"/>
            <DataField Name="postVoidAmount" Type="Data" FieldName="POST_VOID_AMOUNT"/>
            <DataField Name="returnQuantity" Type="Data" FieldName="RETURN_QUANTITY"/>
            <DataField Name="returnAmount" Type="Data" FieldName="RETURN_AMOUNT"/>  

        </ReportElement>
        <ReportElement Type="Detail" Name="DepartmentTotals" DataSource="TotalsDataSql" MaxResults="1">
            <DataField Name="ssSales" Type="Data" FieldName="LINE_NUM_50"/>
            <DataField Name="cigeratteSales" Type="Data" FieldName="LINE_NUM_30"/>
            <DataField Name="liquorSales" Type="Data" FieldName="LINE_NUM_60"/>
            <DataField Name="totalSales" Type="Data" FieldName="TOTAL_FRONT_END_SALES"/>
        </ReportElement>

        <ReportElement Type="Header" DataSource="DateSQL">
            <DataField Name="CurrentDate" Type="Data" FieldName="1" />
            <DataField Name="currentTime" Type="Data" FieldName="2" />
        </ReportElement>
    </ReportBand>
    <DataSource
        Type="walgreens.pos.maintenance.eod.CurrentDepartmentSalesReportDataSource"
        Name="DataSql"
        Statement="">
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource
        Type="walgreens.pos.maintenance.eod.DepartmentTotalsReportDataSource"
        Name="TotalsDataSql"
        Statement="">
    </DataSource>
    <DataSource
        Type="com.pcmsgroup.v21.star.framework.application.reports.SpringReadOnlySQLStatement"
        Name="OutletSQL"
        Statement="select ORGU_CODE,OUTL_TRADE_DATE from outlet,org_unit where outlet.OUTL_ID = org_unit.OUTL_ID">
    </DataSource>

    <DataSource
        Type="com.pcmsgroup.v21.star.framework.application.reports.SpringReadOnlySQLStatement"
        Name="DateSQL"
        Statement="SELECT current date,current time FROM sysibm.sysdummy1">
    </DataSource>

</Report>
```

I just want to know that in xsl there are following lines ..

```
 <fo:block border-bottom-style="solid" text-align="left"
                font-size="9pt" space-before="3mm" />
            <fo:block font-size="9pt" space-after="4mm">

                <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="1.5cm" />
                    <fo:table-column column-width="4.5cm" />
                    <fo:table-column column-width="3.3cm" />

                    <fo:table-header>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold"></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block text-align="left" space-after="4mm"
                                    space-before="3mm" font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>DEPARTMENT TOTALS</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>

                        </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-header>

                    <fo:table-body>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>SS SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right">
                                    <xsl:variable name="ssSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/ssSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$ssSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$ssSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$ssSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>CIGARETTE SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block text-align="right" font-weight="bold">
                                <xsl:variable name="cigeratteSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/cigeratteSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$cigeratteSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$cigeratteSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$cigeratteSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block space-after="1.5mm" font-weight="bold">
                                    <xsl:text>LIQUOR SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right"
                                    space-after="4mm">
                                    <xsl:variable name="liquorSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/liquorSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$liquorSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$liquorSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$liquorSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-row>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block></fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" space-after="8mm">
                                    <xsl:text>TOTAL FRONT END SALES</xsl:text>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                            <fo:table-cell>
                                <fo:block font-weight="bold" text-align="right"
                                    space-after="4mm">
                                    <xsl:variable name="totalSales"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DepartmentSalesReport/DepartmentTotals/totalSales,'0.00')"/></xsl:variable>
                                            <xsl:if test="$totalSales='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                            <xsl:if test="$totalSales!='NaN'">
                                            <fo:block text-align="right">
                                                <xsl:value-of
                                                    select="$totalSales"/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                            </xsl:if>
                                </fo:block>
                            </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>

                    </fo:table-body>

                </fo:table>

            </fo:block>
```

Now My query is that why we have chosen three fo:table-column inside fo:table , Please advise..!!

Comment: Please do not remove the content from your question as it means that the answer no longer makes sense. The fact that you have accepted an answer is enough to show that you consider the problem solved.

Comment: However if the question contains sensitive data or there's some other reason why you think it should be deleted entirely, you can flag it for the moderators to look at.

Comment: @Ian Roberts..As this question contain sensitive data so I request you guys to please delete this question all together,Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xslt and you are asking the question *why we have chosen three fo:table-column inside fo:table*.

Anyhow to get proper render in table I think three columns has been chosen. You can have it in single column but it wont appear good and everything will be wrapped into single column. Modify this

`<fo:table border="1pt solid black">` and `<fo:table-row border-top="1pt solid black">` then you can see where table starts and where it ends.

Comment: Thanks Man..you Rock..this is the way I can debug and see myself the start and end..!

Comment: One thing more I want to know for my knowledge is that is this xsl is dynamic enough such that if department entries increased and cannot be adjusted in single page as shown above then this same format of recording the dynamic entries will also continue in the same way. Please advise.

Comment: that is why this xslt is for. even if get increase will be added in next page dynamically, no issues. you can generate 1000 pages.